# How to convert shell script variable from string to an integer

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu

My script has a line that measures the number of instances of a process being run

`procs=$(pgrep -f luminati | wc -l);`

However, even though the content of `$procs` is a numeral, the shell script is not storing `$procs` as an integer. It is being stored as a string.

Therefore I cannot run conditionals like

`if $procs > 3`

Is there any way to convert this variable to integer type?

Comment: PS: [shellcheck](http://shellcheck.net) automatically detects [this](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2210) and other common problems.

Comment: *Everything* in shell is a string. You need to use the correct commands and operators that can *treat* strings as numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In bash `>` is `truncate` which writes to a file. You probably have a file called `3` now. You should use the comparitor `-gt`:

```
if [[ "$procs" -gt 3 ]]; then
    ...
fi
```

Also, you don't have separate types for integers and strings.

Edit:
As @chepner explained, for POSIX compatibility you should use single brackets:

```
if [ "$procs" -gt 3 ];
```

Comment: LOL, indeed I had a file called 3 by using the `>` sign which I knew about but did not think in this context. But your solution is bang on. Thanks.

Comment: '>' is not `truncate` inside `[[ ]]`, it's ascii comparison

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano is right, `>` doesn't truncate inside `[[ ]]`, however it does inside `[ ]`! It's always safer to use `-gt` in my opinion.

Comment: The existence of `[[` strongly implies your shell also has `((...))`. Use `if [ "$procs" -gt 3 ];` for POSIX compatibility or `if (( procs > 3 ));` for readability.

Answer (score 2):

Should be

```
if [[ "$procs" -gt 3 ]]
then
 ...
fi
```

Comment: You mean to use `-gt` rather than `>`?